# How to map dynamic array of input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I have a form with a set of input fields:

```
<form>
 <div class="row">
     <input type="text" name="product[1]">
     <input type="text" name="qty[1]"> 
 </div>
</form>
```

I also add new rows dynamically to the DOM with jquery's clone() function.

What is the best way to increase the index number? Or is there a better way to 'map' the product and qty fields before submitting to a PHP script?

Comment: you could just write `product[]` and `qty[]`, PHP will deal your data like an array

Comment: `product[]` without index

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan,  I tried this, but how will I be able to determine which qty value belongs to which product?

Comment: they are both arrays so e.g. `product[42]` is related to `qty[42]` (and vice-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<form>
 <div class="row">
     <input type="text" name="product[]">
     <input type="text" name="qty[]"> 
 </div>
   <div class="row">
     <input type="text" name="product[]">
     <input type="text" name="qty[]"> 
 </div>
</form>
```